# Simulate mouse movement in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, ubuntu, mouse, automated-tests

**Problem**

Am looking to automatically move the mouse cursor and simulate mouse button clicks from the command-line using an external script. Am not looking to:

- Record mouse movement and playback (e.g., xnee, xmacro)
- Instantly move the mouse from one location to another (e.g., xdotool, Python's warp_pointer)

**Ideal Solution**

What I'd like to do is the following:

1. Edit a simple script file (e.g., `mouse-script.txt`).
2. Add a list of coordinates, movement speeds, delays, and button clicks. For example:

   ```
   (x, y, rate) = (500, 500, 50)
   sleep = 5
   click = left
   ```
3. Run the script: `xsim < mouse-script.txt`.

**Question**

How do you automate mouse movement so that it transitions from its current location to another spot on the screen, at a specific velocity? For example:

```
xdotool mousemove 500 500 --rate 50
```

The `--rate 50` doesn't exist with `xdotool`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

on newer versions of Ubuntu (14.04+), you can use [Autopilot](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/autopilot/python/1.5.0/), a UI testing tool for Ubuntu.  It is made for creating and running user interface tests, but can also be used for basic GUI automation tasks.

to install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-autopilot
```

an example script (Python3) to automate [mouse movement](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/autopilot/python/1.5.0/autopilot.input.Mouse/#autopilot.input.Mouse):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from autopilot.input import Mouse

mouse = Mouse.create()
mouse.move(100, 50)
mouse.click()
```

You would run this just like any other Python3 script.  Watch your mouse pointer move!

Comment: Even after installing python3-autopilot, I'm getting `ImportError: No module named autopilot.input`. Turns out I had to  run using python3. Cheers

Comment: ubuntu `python3` msg is `Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)` but i have the same error `ImportError: No module named autopilot.input` what could i do?

Comment: Dont use pip3 install, but sudo apt install, then no more ImportError

Answer (score 13):

1. Download [`xaut`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xautomation/) for Python
2. Follow the `README` instructions
3. Run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install swig x11proto-xext-dev libx11-dev libxtst-dev
   cd /usr/local/src
   tar zxf xaut-0.2.0.tar.gz
   ./configure
   ```
4. Edit `src/Makefile`
5. Change the `CFLAGS` line as follows:

   ```
   CFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC -fno-stack-protector
   ```
6. Run:

   ```
   make
   ```
7. Copy `/usr/local/src/xaut-0.2.0/python/build/lib/*` to a new directory.
8. Change to that new directory.
9. Copy and paste the following script into `mm.py`:

   ```
   import xaut
   mouse = xaut.mouse()
   delay mouse.move_delay( 100 )
   mouse.move( 500, 500 )
   ```
10. Run the script:

    ```
    python mm.py
    ```

Comment: Also, when you do the steps abobe it will fail on Ubuntu 11.10. First of all in my case in the makefile I had to add the absolute path of libX11.so which is not in /usr/local/lib as the makefile suggests but in usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu. Then when u fix that it can compile again. So change ld -shared to gcc -shared in the makefile and that's it